# Getting JWT token after Django rest framework login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-auth

I'm not sure I understand it correctly. I'm using Django Rest Framework to let user do login (among many other thing obviously). After user Login From IOS App in my case I want to get a token and to work with the token from there on, so they need to login only once as long as the token is valid.

I got both parts working, the login with username or email and the get token working with curl (like in the JWT manual shows).

How do I combine the both, so if the login is successful, before the response of the login, I will call the JWT, create token and then return it to the response of the login, and the app will get the token with the response.

I'm not sure it is suppose to be done like that, and I would like to do it in one call to the API, not two.  It seem very simple with two, but any call that is not needed shouldn't be done in my eyes.

```
class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user_id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    token = CharField(allow_blank=True, read_only=True)
    username = CharField(required=False, allow_blank= True)
    email = EmailField(label='Email Address', required=False, allow_blank= True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'user_id',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'token',
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def validate(self, data):
        user_obj = None
        email = data.get("email", None)
        username = data.get("username", None)
        password = data["password"]

        if not email and not username:
            raise ValidationError("A username or email is required to login.")

        user = User.objects.filter(
                Q(email=email) |
                Q(username=username)
                ).distinct()
        user = user.exclude(email__isnull=True).exclude(email__iexact='')

        if user.exists() and user.count() == 1:
            user_obj = user.first()
        else:
            raise ValidationError("This username/email is not valid!")

        if user_obj:
            if not user_obj.check_password(password):
                raise ValidationError("Incorrect credentials, please try again!")


        data["token"] = "SOME RANDOM TOKEN"
        data["user_id"] = user_obj.id

        return data
```

I'm returning the token in the data, so all I need is a way to get the token from JWT before that and then return the data just as I'm doing here.

Thanks

Comment: are you using the jwt views?

Comment: Sorry, i don't think i understand the question.... Do you mean django rest framework JWT? What views? There is a framework for Django called "REST framework JWT Auth", I'm using that, it does the tokenizeation for you, calling "curl -X POST -d "username=admin&password=abc123" http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/" will create and return the token and then you can send the token back and forth from the client to the server... i need to call that from the django rest framework, not form the IOS App if there is a way to do that, 10x

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that because [django-rest-framework JWT](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) manage all the tokens for you.

With just:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    # ...

    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
]
```

You will be allowed to get the JWT.

Also, you can set a custom user payload after create/login the user specifying the JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER in you settings.py file.